# Kuberhealthy Check - check NodeGroup labels are matching

Tags: python

This is quite a specific script I have written, for Kubernetes Cluster monitoring purposes (specifically the Nodes). Essentially, I need to ensure that the Nodes within a NodeGroup all have the same labels and label values, or else they will not be scaled out evenly for Node Scale out in the version of Kubernetes we are using (Cluster Auto Scaler wants the values to be the same in order to treat the Nodes equally).

The env var IN_CLUSTER is used so I can set whether the script is run from my local machine (which can read kubectl config) or whether it's running as a container within the cluster (leverage RBAC permissions).

The script I have written works and does what I need - get a list of Nodes in the cluster, iterate through each NodeGroup (there are four Node Groups - core, general, observability, pci). We group the Nodes into their relevant NodeGroup. We then check each Node within the NodeGroup, and do a comparison to ensure the labels match.

The script implements the Kubernetes client for retrieving list of Nodes. The script also implements the Kuberhealthy client, which is simply to report the check results (success or failure) to the Kuberhealthy master.

I do not like the fact that the four NodeGroups are hardcoded in the script but can't think how to achieve what I want with an array stored as an env var.

The script is intended to simply run top to bottom and be simple. I'm not sure it makes sense to have the `if __name__ == '__main__'` directive as it's never going to be imported as a module.

````
from kubernetes import client, config
from kh_client import *
import os

# requires cluster role with permissions list, get nodes!
# needs refactoring, for time being have kept it as a 'top to bottom' script

def main():
    if os.getenv('IN_CLUSTER') == "TRUE":
        config.load_incluster_config()
    else:
        config.load_kube_config()
    
    try:
        api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
        node_list = api_instance.list_node()
    except client.exceptions.ApiException:
        print("401 Unauthorised. Please check you are authenticated for the target cluster / have set the IN_CLUSTER env var.")
        exit(2)

    node_group_core = []
    node_group_general = []
    node_group_observability = []
    node_group_pci = []

    # print("%s\t\t%s" % ("NAME", "LABELS"))
    # this needs changing but difficult to do with an env_var
    for node in node_list.items:
        if node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name') == "core":
            node_group_core.append(node)
        if node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name') == "general":
            node_group_general.append(node)
        if node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name') == "observability":
            node_group_observability.append(node)
        if node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name') == "pci":
            node_group_pci.append(node)

    check_node_group_labels(node_group_core)
    check_node_group_labels(node_group_general)
    check_node_group_labels(node_group_observability)
    check_node_group_labels(node_group_pci)

    # everything has checked successfully, report success. 
    print("Reporting Success.")
    try:
        report_success()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error when reporting success: {e}")

def check_node_group_labels(node_group):
    # ignored labels taken from https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/3a69f118d95cd653bf101aecc0ea5e00bf7ba370/cluster-autoscaler/processors/nodegroupset/aws_nodegroups.go#L26
    # this can be refactored
    ignored_labels = [ "alpha.eksctl.io/instance-id", 
                       "alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name", 
                       "eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup", 
                       "k8s.amazonaws.com/eniConfig",
                       "lifecycle",
                       # labels i've added
                       "topology.kubernetes.io/zone",
                       "kubernetes.io/hostname",
                       "failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone" ]

    node_group_labels = []
    for l in node_group[0].metadata.labels:
        if l not in ignored_labels:
            node_group_labels.append(l)

    print(f"There are {len(node_group)} nodes in {node_group[0].metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')}")

    for label in node_group_labels:
        # compare against the 'benchmark' label, any difference means a mismatch as far as CAS is concerned
        # print(label)
        benchmark_label = node_group[0].metadata.labels.get(label)
        # print("benchmark label: ", benchmark_label)
        for node in node_group[1:]:
            # print("node label", node.metadata.labels.get(label))
            if node.metadata.labels.get(label) != benchmark_label:
                print("Reporting Failure.")
                try:
                    report_failure([f"Warning! label mismatch detected, for nodegroup and node {node.metadata.name}, benchmark value: {benchmark_label}, this node value: {node.metadata.labels.get(label)}"])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error when reporting failure: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```
````

Answer (score 5):

Regarding:

> I do not like the fact that the four NodeGroups are hardcoded in the
> script but can't think how to achieve what I want with an array stored
> as an env var.

We can start first by creating a dictionary with all the `node_groups` and then start to refactor a bit of our code:

```
NODE_GROUPS = {
    'core': [],
    'general': [],
    'observability': [],
    'pci': [],
}
```

By doing this, we'll remove some of the duplicate code we have in the `main` function:

```
def main():
    # ...
    for node in node_list.items:
        nodegroup_name = node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')

        for node_group_name, nodes in NODE_GROUPS.items():
            if nodegroup_name == node_group_name:
                nodes.append(node)

    for node_group in NODE_GROUPS.values():
        check_node_group_labels(node_group)
    
    # ...
```

Now, storing `NODE_GROUPS` into a config file wouldn't be a great idea because the new format would not help us. If you really want to take the node groups out I'd suggest you use a different method.

---

> I'm not sure it makes sense to have the `if __name__ == '__main__'`
> directive as it's never going to be imported as a module.

This guard is boilerplate code that protects users from accidentally invoking the script when they didn't intend to. Here are some common problems when the guard is omitted from a script:

- If you import the guardless script in another script (e.g. `import my_script_without_a_name_eq_main_guard`), then the second script will trigger the first to run at import time and using the second script's command line arguments. This is almost always a mistake.
- If you have a custom class in the guardless script and save it to a pickle file, then unpickling it in another script will trigger an import of the guardless script, with the same problems outlined in the previous bullet.

I'd say it's usually good practice to have it in your code but not mandatory. To read more about it [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/8605514)

Here's how I'd style the whole script:

```
import os
import sys

from kh_client import *
from kubernetes import client, config


NODE_GROUPS = {
    'core': [],
    'general': [],
    'observability': [],
    'pci': [],
}
IGNORED_LABELS = (
    "alpha.eksctl.io/instance-id",
    "alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-name",
    "eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup",
    "k8s.amazonaws.com/eniConfig",
    "lifecycle",
    
    # custom labels
    "topology.kubernetes.io/zone",
    "kubernetes.io/hostname",
    "failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone"
)


def load_config():
    if os.getenv('IN_CLUSTER') == "TRUE":
        config.load_incluster_config()
    else:
        config.load_kube_config()


def get_nodes():
    try:
        api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()
        return api_instance.list_node()
    except client.exceptions.ApiException:
        print("401 Unauthorised. Please check you are authenticated "
              "for the target cluster / have set the IN_CLUSTER env "
              "var.")
        sys.exit(2)
        
        
def get_group_labels(node_group):
    return [
        node_group_label for node_group_label in node_group[0].metadata.labels
        if node_group_label not in IGNORED_LABELS
    ]


def check_node_group_labels(node_group):
    node_group_labels = get_group_labels(node_group)

    print(f"There are {len(node_group)} nodes in "
          f"{node_group[0].metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')}")

    for label in node_group_labels:
        # compare against the 'benchmark' label, any difference means 
        # a mismatch as far as CAS is concerned
        benchmark_label = node_group[0].metadata.labels.get(label)
        
        for node in node_group[1:]:
            label = node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')
            if label != benchmark_label:
                print("Reporting Failure.")
                
                try:
                    report_failure([
                        f"Warning! label mismatch detected, for nodegroup and "
                        f"node {node.metadata.name}, benchmark value: {benchmark_label}, "
                        f"this node value: {label}"
                    ])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error when reporting failure: {e}")


def main():
    load_config()
    nodes = get_nodes()

    for node in nodes.items:
        nodegroup_name = node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')

        for node_group_name, group_nodes in NODE_GROUPS.items():
            if nodegroup_name == node_group_name:
                group_nodes.append(node)

    for node_group in NODE_GROUPS.values():
        check_node_group_labels(node_group)

    print("Reporting Success.")
    try:
        report_success()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error when reporting success: {e}")
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't tested this as I don't have any kube cluster but here are some of the things I've improved:

- create smaller functions to easier allow writing unit tests / check the correctness of your code
- improved some variable names
- reordered the imports
- `exit` is a helper for the interactive shell - `sys.exit` is intended for use in programs. Use the second one.

---

Homework for OP:

- try adding docstrings to your code;
- avoid using bare excepts unless necessary

Comment: That's brilliant thanks very much. Will take a look at your suggestions now and feed back in due course.

Comment: this code here (line 65 in yours) causes my script to fail... i dont think it's doing what it looks like (not sure if it conflicts with 'label' defined above) 
```label = node.metadata.labels.get(label)```

Comment: Oupsie, that should actually be: `label = node.metadata.labels.get('nodegroup-name')`